# GetRegionsHierarchy failing on documents with barcodes

Tags: .net, mailmerge, aspose.words

I am using Aspose Words (.Net) and trying to get a region overview of the word document. The problem I am having is that this fails as soon as the document has `MERGEBARCODE` fields.

```
var regions = doc.MailMerge.GetRegionsHierarchy();
```

Throws an error: `Unable to cast object of type 'Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldMergeBarcode' to type 'Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldMergeField'.`

Has anybody else come across this, or does anyone know if there is a way to get this to work?

Comment: Please try [latest version of Aspose.Words for .NET i.e. 18.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/). In case the problem still remains, please ZIP and Upload your input Word document to Dropbox and share the download link here for testing. We will investigate the issue on our end and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/toit76ow6gnt3hl/10282_Doc1.docx?dl=0

Comment: It seems that `GetRegionsHierarchy` is generating a list of `FieldMergeField`s instead of the more generic `Field`.

Comment: We tested the scenario and have managed to reproduce the same exception on our end. For the sake of correction, we have logged this problem in our issue tracking system. The ID of this issue is WORDSNET-16442. Our product team will further look into the details of this problem and we will keep you updated on the status of correction. We apologize for your inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The issues you have found earlier (filed as WORDSNET-16442) have been fixed in [this Aspose.Words for .NET 18.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/18.3.0) update and [this Aspose.Words for Java 18.3 update](http://maven.aspose.com/repository/simple/ext-release-local/com/aspose/aspose-words/18.3/).